# Connect sockets directly after introduction through server

Tags: chat, p2p

I'm looking for the name of a protocol and example code that permits handing off IP/port connections to establish unmediated P2P after introduction through a server.

*Simple example:*

You and I both start chat programs that connect to chatintroduce.com (fictional server). I send you a "Hi!  Wanna chat?" message. It doesn't get sent.  Instead my chat program tells chatintroduce to send your chat program a request for connection. You respond to a prompt and your chat program tells chatintroduce to broker the connection. Chatintroduce establishes an initial two-way connection between us. Now, this final step is important, chatintroduce releases control and our two chat programs now talk directly to each other without any traffic through chatintroduce.

In other words,  I construct packets which have your IP address and you receive them without interference from firewalls, NATs or any other technologies.  In other words, `true peer-to-peer` connection independent of intermediate server.

I need to know what search terms to use to find appropriate technology.  An RFC name would suffice.  I've been searching for days without success.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is TCP/UDP hole punching which typically coordinates the P2P connection using a STUN server to determine the "capabilities" of the firewalls (e.g. is it a full cone nat? symmetric?).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)

We employed this at a company I worked for to create a kind of BitTorrent that could circumvent firewalls for streaming video between two peers.

Note that sometimes it is NOT possible to establish a connection without the intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is ICE protocol. [RFC 5245](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5245). This protocol is used for connecting two peers through NAT traversal. There are some open source libraries and also some proprietary libraries for this. You can search google with ICE implementation.

You will also need to read about some additional protocols. These are used with ICE protocol. They are [STUN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5389) and [TURN](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5766).

For some cases you can't make P2P call 100% time. You will have to use a relay server. Like if the NAT combination of two peers are Symmetric vs Symmetric/PRC. That relay server is called TURN server.

Some technique like Port forwarding and TCP/UDP hole punching will help you to increase P2P rates.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31424904/what-type-of-nat-combinations-requires-a-turn-server) for more information about which combination of NAT will require a relay server and which don't.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.  I will be looking further into ICE, STUN, TURN, and hole-punching.
I also found n2n which looks like almost exactly what I wanted.

```
https://github.com/meyerd/n2n
http://xmodulo.com/configure-peer-to-peer-vpn-linux.html
```

With n2n, one makes a VPN with a super node that all other edge nodes know.
But once the introductions are made, the super node can be absent.
This was exactly what I wanted.  I hope it works across platforms (linux, MacOS, Windows).
Again, I am still researching before implementation, so your advice was very important to me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use PJNATH. Its open source.

http://www.pjsip.org/pjnath/docs/html/

There is not much open source on NAT Traversal. As far as I know PJNATH is good.

For server you can use Google's Open source STUN and TURN server.